# Bootstrap hide not work properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a following code :

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="hidden-xs">
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and I expect it to be invisible when width will be smaller than 480px as it's default value in bootstrap css files. However, using Google Chrome simulator it becomes invisible when I set width smaller than 768 - so it works like hidden-sm. When I change hidden-xs to hidden-xs-down it always stays visible.

What I do wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should double or triple check that your page loads **jQuery** before anything else. After that should follow the Bootstrap's JS and CSS libraries.

Bootstrap's default class `hidden-xs` should work just fine if the framework is able to load correctly, no changes to any CSS or JS required at any point. I would also like to mention that `hidden-xs-down` is not Bootstrap standard, and that explains why it does not work.

What comes to the default breakpoints, **768px is actually XS**, while 992px is SM and so forth.

In case you want the div to disappear when the width is below 480px, you should **create your own class**. To do so, just put the following to your CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 480px)
{
   .hidden-xxs { display: none; }
}
```

Comment: I use jQuery v1.10.2 and Bootstrap v3.3.5

Comment: I updated my answer, I just realized that your `hidden-xs` class works just the way it should be, since everything below 768px is considered XS by default. Make your own class to solve your problem. :)

Comment: Right, I misunderstood those ranges. Thanks

Comment: No problem! Mark the question answered and come back if you encounter another block on your path. :)